# Как разбить строку и передать в execv?

Tags: c++, linux, exec

Запрашивается строка из ввода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string argums;
    cout << "Write arguments: ";
    getline(cin, argums);
    execvp("python3", ...);
    return 0;
}
```

А как разбить строку на слова и вместить в `execve()`? Ведь заранее неизвестно, какой длины будет строка, сколько в ней будет слов?

Comment: Например записать слова в в массив строк `vector<string>` и передать в функцию ссылку на массив

Comment: пробую execve("python3", "python3", argums);. Не помогает, хотя vector<string> argums, ему надо const char*

Comment: не так. Вы считываете строку в `argums`. Потом делите на слова (ищете пробел) и слова записываете в массив `vector<string> arg`. Потом в функцию передаете ссылку на массив слов `execvp(arg);`

Comment: вы собираетесь ввести путь с консоли?  Просто передайте int argc  и char **argv  функции main и получите  argv. И зачем для передачи в функцию низкого уровня использовать С++ строки?

Comment: Я вообще аргументы считаю так: помещают ввод в stringstream argstream, затем while (argstream >> singlearg) { argums.push_back(singlearg); }. И я не могу без stringstream, для разбиения на пробелы(

Comment: Помимо разбиения по пробелам еще следует обрабатывать кавычки и экранирующие последовательности.

Comment: @user7860670 Да, я знаю. Но конкретно для этой задачи, где аргументы запрашиваются в определенном формате, вероятно достаточно какого-то одного конкретного разделителя - пробел или точка, или запятая и т.д.